# Obtaining key's index in python dictionary/hash table

Tags: python

I'm trying to obtain the key's index. Let's say i have:

```
Jamie: 3
Alan:  5
Dwayne: 4
```

and the keys are the names and values are the digits. What i want now is accessing the key's index in this case, the key Jamie is at index 0, Alan at 1 and Dwayne at 2.

I'm not familiar with this as I'm more used to obtaining the index from a normal list.

Do i do something like:

```
for i, value in enumerate(dict):
     if dict[i] != ...
```

It doesn't seemed right and i'll appreciate some feedback on this.

Comment: There is no index in dict structure. What you see is just a printout format.

Comment: Normal `dict` has no order, hence index of keys are not available. You might be interested in [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which remembers the order that keys were first inserted.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned since dict doesn't store key,value pair in order by default, you will need to convert to `orderedDict` as below

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict(d)
>>> d
OrderedDict([('Jamie', 3), ('Dwayne', 4), ('Alan', 5)])
```

After that dict's key index will be ordered

```
>>> d.keys()
['Jamie', 'Dwayne', 'Alan']
```

Then you can either use

```
>>> d.keys().index('Alan')
2
```

OR enumerate method that your are trying. ( Need to add iterator there)

```
>>> for i,value in enumerate(d.iteritems()):
    print i,value


0 ('Jamie', 3)
1 ('Dwayne', 4)
2 ('Alan', 5)
>>>
```

Here you can access individual key,value as a 0,1 index of tuple.

```
>>> for i,value in enumerate(d.iteritems()):
    print i, value[0], value[1]


0 Jamie 3
1 Dwayne 4
2 Alan 5
>>>
```

Comment: This isn't really the index of the string inside of the dict, rather it's the index of the string inside the list of keys. Sort of misleading here.

Comment: @wiggyA, yes I am aware that.Thanks for pointing out. Was still working on answer when I hit submit. Added remaining contents.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
for key in dict:
    if key != ...
```

and you can use `dict[key]` to get corresponding value if the statement is met